# How old were James and Lily Potter when they died?

Tags: harry-potter

How old were Harry Potter's parents when Voldemort killed them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[James](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/James_Potter_I) and [Lily's headstone](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lily_J._Potter) (see in the Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows book) states that they were both 21 years of age when they died.

> *James Potter, born 27 March 1960, died 31 October 1981*
>
> *Lily Potter, born 30 January 1960, died 31 October 1981*
>
> *The last
> enemy that shall be destroyed is death.*

And as seen in the HP and Deathly Hallows, Part II film

[image]

---

For the record, the actors that portrayed them in the films were born in 1967 ([Geraldine Somerville](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0813893/)) and 1958 ([Adrian Rawlins](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0712628/)), making them 34 and 43 at the time of filming Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, almost twice the supposed age of their characters. No explanation is given for their aged appearance.

[image]

Comment: Only 21 years old? They looked older in the movies. Like they were mid-30's.

Comment: @RichS - Hence the usual "the movies are nonsense" disclaimer.

Comment: Their appearance in the Mirror of Erised shows Harry's heart's desire, so their reflections' ages would have kept pace with his.

Comment: @Gaultheria - We see them in the later films looking much the same ages

Comment: True, though the screenshot shows the Mirror; maybe a still from one of the later films would work better here, although the framing is very good in this one.  The actors may have been kept on after *Philosopher's Stone* to help the movies maintain a consistent look, even though this broke continuity on a deeper level.

Comment: @Gaultheria That's a great point btw! What actually happens is that we, the audience, look into that mirror. We do not want to see a 21 year old frat boy/bully James and teasing-Snape-into-lifelong-depression young Lilly, we want to see people that look as if they could be parents. Our  heat's desire is that Harry's father isn't a guy someone would call "bro" (or "mate" I think in England?)

Comment: @Raditz_35 - Harry speaks unaccented middle-class RP English. He wouldn't generally call an older boy/man his "mate" nor his "bro".

Comment: @Valorum That's why I wrote someone and not Harry.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Well, also that Harry probably desires that his parents were _still alive_ and never died, so they would appear in the Mirror as having aged.

Comment: @tobiasvl That is what Gaul... wrote. We've finally come full circle!

Comment: @Raditz_35 But when they appear in DH2, they are ghosts (or ghost-like souls), not imaginings within a mirror. The others (Sirius and Remus) who appear at the same time when Harry uses the Stone are shown at the ages they died, but not the Potters.

Comment: @RichS That's DH2. I still think on it's own, one can justify this for the first movie. Another example: Just because Rambo 3 is really bad doesn't mean Rambo 1 is also bad. 2 different movies. Btw, I'm guessing you are talking about my now deleted first comment? Gaultheria made a great observation that made that one obsolete.

Comment: @RichS, presumably the spirits brought back by the Stone appear as the age they would have been were they still alive.  That's true of both Harry's parents and Sirius and Remus, and makes sense given the Stone's (nominal) backstory.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Do you have a canon source that says spirits appear the age as if they were still alive? If that were the case, Rowena Ravenclaw's spirit would look 1000 years old.

Comment: @RichS, no, if I had a canon source I wouldn't have said "presumably". :-)  My guess is consistent with the relevant scene in *Hallows*, but there are other possibilities.  AFAIK we never see Rowena's spirit, do you mean Helena's ghost?  Ghosts aren't the same thing at all, because they're permanently stuck in this world and they don't belong here.  (Which probably means that a spirit summoned by the Stone and kept for a long period wouldn't age during that time.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I meant Helena Ravenclaw when I wrote about the ghost.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Actually, in the books, those brought back by the Stone seem to appear younger than they were when they died, or at least Sirius (who was "younger by far than Harry had seen him in life") and Remus (who "was younger too, and much less shabby, and his hair was thicker and darker") do.

Comment: @BolteAltamont, I'd interpret that as being because Sirius and Remus were prematurely aged by a harsh life.  But I don't recall whether the books ever mentioned what age the spirits of Harry's parents appeared, so it may only be an issue in the movies.